How to use clientID on Adguard Home with Nginx reverse proxy
I have my server to use Adguard home and Nginx reverse proxy. But it's only work on my second level subdomain. Now I want to use clientID on AGH, but it need subdomain of current AGH domain.
Example: my domain is example.site, my AGH domain is blockads.example.site, I want to use ID:phone so DoH url is phone.blockads.example.site/dns-query, but when I use this link, it redirect me to blank page (it can't detect the phone in blockads.example.site)
Nginx config:

events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http{
    server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    upstream adguard-home {
        server localhost:8110;
        keepalive 64;

    server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        server_name _;
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }

    server {
        listen                                 443 ssl;
        server_name                            blockads.hgmusic963.site;    

        ssl_certificate                        D:/NetworkServices/Certs/cert.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key                    D:/NetworkServices/Certs/privkey.pem;
        ssl_protocols                          TLSv1.3;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers              off;
        ssl_stapling                           on;
        ssl_stapling_verify                    on;

        location /dns-query {
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For   $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_set_header                   Host $host;
            proxy_set_header                   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_pass                         https://localhost:8110/dns-query;
        }

        
        location / {
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_set_header                   Host $host;
            proxy_set_header                   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_pass                         https://adguard-home;
            proxy_redirect                     / /;
            proxy_cookie_path                  / /;
        }
    }
}

How can I do to use this feature on my domain?
